# What is the relationship between the eigenvalues of $Z^T V Z$ and $Z^T Z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ where $p \leq n$ and $rank(Z)=p$. $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is positive definite matrix and we set $tr(V)=n$. Suppose $\lambda_1(\cdot) \geq \dots\geq\lambda_p(\cdot)$ are the eigenvalues of matrix $\cdot$. Is there any relationship or inequalities between $\lambda_i(Z^TVZ)$ and $\lambda_i(Z^TZ)$ for $i=1,\dots,p$?

Comment: If the eigenvalues of $V$ are all greater than $1$, then $\lambda_i(Z^TVZ) \geq \lambda_i(Z^TZ)$. If the eigenvalues of $V$ are all less than $1$, then $\lambda_i(Z^TVZ) \leq \lambda_i(Z^TZ)$. I don't believe that there's anything stronger than that which we can say more generally.

Comment: Are you interested in a proof of this fact? If so, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to say that $tr(V)=n$. So there are some eigenvalues of $V$ greater than 1 and others are less than 1.

Comment: I am also very interested in the proof of your first comment. Could you show it as an answer or comment? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim:** If the eigenvalues of $V$ are all greater than or equal to 1, then $\lambda_i(Z^TVZ) \geq \lambda_i(Z^TZ)$. If the eigenvalues of $V$ are all less than or equal to $1$ then $\lambda_i(Z^TVZ) \leq \lambda_i(Z^TZ)$.

*Proof:* If the eigenvalues of $V$ are all greater than or equal to $1$, then $V - I$ is positive semidefinite. It follows that $Z^T(V-I)Z$ is positive semidefinite. It follows from [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory) that
$$
\lambda_i(Z^TVZ) = \lambda_i(Z^TZ + Z^T(V - I)Z) \geq \lambda_i(Z^TZ) + \lambda_\min(Z^T(V - I)Z) \geq \lambda_i(Z^TZ).
$$
Similarly, if the eigenvalues of $V$ are all less than or equal to $1$, then $I - V$ is positive semidefinite. It follows that $Z^T(I - V)Z$ is positive semidefinite, so that
$$
\lambda_i(Z^TZ) = \lambda_i(Z^TVZ + Z^T(I - V)Z) \geq \lambda_i(Z^TVZ) + \lambda_\min(Z^T(I - V)Z) \geq \lambda_i(Z^TVZ).
$$